# How to get DensityHistogram bins like GeoHistogram bins?

Tags: histograms, charts

Version 11 introduced [`GeoHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoHistogram.html).  It creates bins that align the edges with certain shapes.  [`DensityHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityHistogram.html) can also use different shapes but its bins remain rectangular so that the shapes do no align.

Is there a way to get `DensityHistogram` to bin over the shape regions as `GeoHistogram` does? I suppose I could workout some transformation to geo-coordinates and use `GeoHistogram` but I'm hoping there is a means to avoid this hackery.

```
data = CityData[{All, "Iceland"}];
```

With `"Hexagon"`

```
GeoHistogram[data, ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", GeoBackground -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DensityHistogram[EntityValue[data, {"Longitude", "Latitude"}], 
 ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", 
 ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementDataFunction["Bubble", "Shape" -> "Hexagon"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With `"Triangle"`

```
GeoHistogram[data, "Triangle", ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", 
 GeoBackground -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DensityHistogram[EntityValue[data, {"Longitude", "Latitude"}], 
 ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", 
 ChartElementFunction -> 
  ChartElementDataFunction["Bubble", "Shape" -> "Triangle"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If you decide to implement it yourself, [this](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1474/605) may be helpful.

Comment: @Szabolcs Looks as if you've done a bit of the heavy lifting already.